# Looping over a txt file for data processing in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a text file having the following data. The total lines are 162 comprising of the same data

```
0000
0000
0000
1111
2222
3333
3333
4444
5555
6666
7777
8888
0000
0000
0000
1111
2222
3333
3333
4444
5555
6666
7777
8888
```

I want to loop over this file, find the '0000 0000 0000' data pattern that repeats on 3 consecutive lines and save the next lines in a list for data processing. 
This is a part of code that i have written.
Here i check if 0000 appears in the list, once i get it, i delete the 3 consecutive pattern and send the list for data processing, however the logic doesnt seem to work, as it takes all the data of the next pattern too. Can anybody help me here?

```
match = 0000
values = []
bit_file = open(filename, 'rb')
for line in bit_file:
    values.append(line.strip("\n"))
print values

for val in values:       
    if (val == match):
        del values[0:3]
        print("deleted\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        processdata(values)
```

Comment: A number is never equal to a string (even if the string represents a number). But that is only the first problem.

Comment: okay..so il have to convert the list into a int list for my case then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('test.txt') as fp:
    data = [line.strip() for line in fp]
    data = ' '.join([' '.join(data[i: i + 3]) for i in range(0, len(data), 3)])
    data = [list(map(int, x.split())) for x in data.split('0000 0000 0000') if x]
    print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1111, 2222, 3333, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888], [1111, 2222, 3333, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea,..but i was looking for the data in batches for processing..like the data from 1111 to 8888 in one list, process that first and move onto the next data

Comment: one doubt here, ..how do i convert the final sublist items into base 32 or hex numbers ?

Comment: @komatiraju032..thanks a lot..the previous solution actually worked..please can you post both the codes? Also the conversion doesnt work if the input numbers are "FFF0004B" 32bit number

Comment: @dipk11 change `list(map(int, x.split()))` to `x.split()`

Comment: @ komatiraju032, the sublist data will be stored as string in this case right? for input file having the data 'FFF0004B' and so on...how do i convert the final data list into 32 bit hex number if i use only x.split() method..i will be using this List for further matrix multiplication

Comment: @dipk11 just create new function `to_hex()`  to convert your string to hex then use map to apply that function on every string in the list `list(map(to_hex, x.split()))`

Answer (score 0):

You always delete the first three values in the list instead of the ones matching your pattern. Try modifying your for-loop like this:

```
    found_match = 0
    for idx, val in enumerate(values):
        if (int(val) == match):
            found_match += 1
            if (found_match == 3):
                del values[idx-2:idx+1]
                print("deleted\n\n\n\n\n\n")
                processdata(values)
        else:
            found_match = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a generator function that **yields** results on demand efficiently:

```
def read_data():
    with open("<your file>") as f:
        counter, sublist = 0, []
        for line in f:
            if line.strip() == "0000":
                counter += 1
                if sublist and counter == 3:
                    yield sublist
                    sublist = []
                continue

            counter = 0
            sublist.append(int(line.strip()))
        else:
            yield sublist
```

Using the function `read_data()`:

```
for data in read_data():
    # TODO: process the data 
    # processdata(data)
    print(data)
```

This prints:

```
[1111, 2222, 3333, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888]
[1111, 2222, 3333, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888]
```